# count paired numbers in 2-dimension python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, match

This is a typical python coding challenge. Many beginners have a hard time handling it.

For example, we have a test array as:

`test = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,4],[2,1],[2],[5,1],[3,4]]`

Q1: count the number of pairs in the list.

Q2: count the number of pairs for 1.

I know I can use the least/greatest function in SQL to do the job, but I don't know how to do it in python, especially in 2 dimension arrays.

Expected result for Q1 is 5 ([1,2],[1,3],[2,4],[5,1],[3,4]）

Expected result for Q2 is 3 (2,3,5)

Comment: You don't need max at all.  `len(k for k in test if len(k)==2)` and `len(k for k in test if len(k)==2 and 1 in k)`

Comment: It's not clear why Q2 includes `[2,1]` and Q1 doesn't.

Comment: Aren't there six pairs?

Comment: Looking again it looks like @kpie edited the `[2, 1]` into Q2. That's probably a bad edit that makes the question inconsistent. I've rolled it back. (please be careful when editing the content of questions @kpie).

Comment: @Tim Python gives me an error if I try to use len that way: `object of type 'generator' has no len()`. Maybe there's a version difference here

Comment: So just add square brackets to turn it into a list: `len([k...2])`.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

```py
test = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,4],[2,1],[2],[5,1],[3,4]]

unordered_pairs = set(frozenset(l) for l in test if len(l) == 2)
print(unordered_pairs)
# {frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({2, 4}), frozenset({1, 5}), frozenset({1, 3})}

q1 = len(unordered_pairs)
q2 = sum(1 in p for p in unordered_pairs)
print(q1, q2) # 5 3
```

Comment: Why use a set at all?  Totally unnecessary.

Comment: @TimRoberts I guess the OP wanted `[1, 2]` to be equal to `[2, 1]`, so I used `frozenset` for that. As for `set`, the OP didn't count `[1, 2]` and `[2, 1] (= [1, 2])` separately, so I used `set`. Maybe there's something I am missing here.

Comment: It looks like it was a bad edit by @kpie that made the two results inconsistent.

Comment: I didn't realize that frozensets are hashable, that's a neat approach

Answer (score -1):

`len([k in test if len(k)==2])` and `len([k for k in test if 1 in k])` should get you there.

Comment: (Some of the entries in the list are NOT pairs...)

Comment: oh yeah huh look at that.